# while(element 'n' not found in vector 'm') how to write it in code format in while loop of R?

Tags: r

while(element 'n' not found in vector 'm'twice. Note:element 'n' may not change in every cycle ) how to write it in while loop in R? Basically, I am trying to terminate a cycle when dectected.

Comment: perhaps using a variation of `if(!n %in% m)...`

Comment: perhaps by providing a reproducible example?